# NestJS Axios module - can't resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, axios, nestjs

I'm having a baffling problem with the NestJS Axios module. I have it imported in my module like so:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';

import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthStrategy } from './auth.strategy';

@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
  imports: [HttpModule, PassportModule, AuthStrategy],
})
```

And I'm attempting to use it in my `AuthStrategy` like so:

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-oauth2';

@Injectable()
export class AuthStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {
    super({
      authorizationURL: `${process.env['OAUTH_DOMAIN']}/authorize`,
      tokenURL: `${process.env['OAUTH_DOMAIN']}/oauth/token`,
      clientID: process.env['OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'],
      clientSecret: process.env['OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'],
      callbackURL: process.env['OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL'],
      scope: ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  async validate(accessToken: string): Promise<any> {
    const data = await this.httpService.get(`${process.env['OAUTH_DOMAIN']}/`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    });

    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthStrategy (?). Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [0] is available in the AuthStrategy context.
```

Where am I going wrong? I've done what the error suggests, but it's still not working

Comment: You have to add `AuthStrategy` in providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your application, you have `AuthStrategy` (a provider) added to a module's `imports` array. Providers should never be in the `imports` arrays.

You can learn more about reading and dissecting the error message [from the docs page](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error).

> There are a few gotchas, that are common. One is putting a provider in an `imports` array. If this is the case, the error will have the provider's name where `<module>` should be.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thanks, that's really useful!